# Unable to show text on mouse over of SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I am trying to show only text whenever the user hover on svg element(a rectangle in my case) either with CSS or JS.

```html
 <svg width="400" height="180">
  <rect x="50" y="20" width="150" height="150"
  style="fill:blue;stroke:pink;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:0.1;stroke-opacity:0.9" />
  <text class="img__description" x="50" y="100" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="blue">Hello</text>
</svg>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add css styles to the elements of the svg, e.g. `display: none`.

**Working example**:

```css
svg:hover rect {
    display: none;
}

svg text {
    display: none;
}

svg:hover text {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="180">
  <rect x="50" y="20" width="150" height="150"
    style="fill:blue;stroke:pink;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:0.1;stroke-opacity:0.9"
  />
  <text class="img__description" x="50" y="100" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="blue">Hello</text>
</svg>
```